# Improving a bad CNN- Detecting Image Orientation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

just starting out in ML and finally got my first CNN up and running :) except its accuracy is only slightly better than a random guess (~27%). I give the model a set of 2000 pictures of faces sorted into either 0 degrees, 90 degrees, 180 degrees, or 270 degrees rotated. Below is my code:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('firstThousandTransformed/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(64,64))
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('validation/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(64,64))
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('test/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64, color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(64,64))

imageInput = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=8, activation='relu')(imageInput)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
flat = Flatten()(pool3)
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(flat)
output = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=imageInput, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=val_it, validation_steps=8)
loss = model.evaluate(test_it, steps=16)

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(train_it)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

print(model.summary())
```

The way I envisioned this network working was that the convolution layers might detect some hair or a chin in a certain place and be able to distinguish that hair or chin placement from another image. This clearly is not working. Could you give a noobie some advice? How can I make this better? How can I think about this problem? Am I using the wrong kind of layers? Do I need more pictures?

EDIT:
So I have been playing around with it a little bit by messing with the kernel_sizes (now they are 12, 8, and 4) and changing the number of epochs to 20, and something crazy happened. When I ran the program, I got an accuracy of 99%!! (see screenshot below)
[image]
HOWEVER, when I ran it again to double check, it went back to ~27%. What does this mean?

Comment: What was your validation accuracy. It is a much better metric to use when checking your results

Comment: Isn't the validation accuracy the val_accuracy in the screenshot? Also, I fixed this issue by turning up the epochs to 25 and turning down the batch_size to 32.